# Shopify Storefront API: Getting referenced variant with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, shopify, variant, storefront

I'm using the Shopify Storefront API and Accentuate to try to get my hands on a specific variant, but it won't work for me.

**THE SHORT VERSION:** When I select a variant on the website, I get the url: *(... url ...)?variant=31696763027492*. How do I get my hands on these numbers after the = for the variant in GraphQL? It does not match the ID.

**THE LONG VERSION...**

In a product variant, I reference to a variant of another product (with Accentuate). What I need to get out is the variant that I am referencing to.

When I pull out the variant that is being referenced to in the product (as metafield, with GraphQL), I get this:

```
{
"key": "products_in_package",
"value": "pakke-produkt-gavepose:31696763027492"
}
```

My problem is the numbers after : in the value. I've found that these are the number that come after the URL of the product when selecting the variant on the "actual" Shopify website ((... url ...)?variant=31696763027492), but I can't see how I can use them, since I can't find these numbers on the actual variant through GraphQL.

It does not match the 'id' or anything else I could find on the variant. Neither can I include the numbers if I try to get productByHandle.

So, does anyone have any ideas on how I can I use it to get the actual product variant through GraphQL? Or ideas on what else I can do to connect a specific product variant to another product variant?

Answer (score 4):

The storefront API and admin API return different format of Id

- storefront API: `"Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzQ3NjA3ODY1MDE3MDM="`
- Admin API: `"gid://shopify/Product/4760786501703"`

**But** there is a **convert** way between each other, use function `atob`

`atob("Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzQ3NjA3ODY1MDE3MDM=")` will get the Admin API Id

For NodeJS package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/atob

Answer (score 2):

The variant ID and GraphQL variant ID is closely related.

- Variant id - `31646396055604`
- GraphQL Variant id - `gid://shopify/ProductVariant/31646396055604`

The GraphQL ID is the same as the Variant id but you must add the string `gid://shopify/ProductVariant/` before it.

So your GraphQL request will become like so:

```
{
  productVariant(id:"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/31646396055604"){
    title
    product{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is (or was) that those numbers are *not* what you get when you get the id from the product through GraphQL. You get a much longer id, like "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8zMTY5NDA3MjQxNDI0NA==".

However, I figures out that using the btoa() JavaScript function on the id you mention (gid://shopify/ProductVariant/31646396055604), I got the long id that I get from the product itself. So problem solved!